# HAPI FHIR not generate Narrative Template

Tags: web-services, hl7-fhir, health-monitoring, hapi

I have a problem with my restful server implements with HAPI FHIR. I have a PatientResourceProvider and a PractitionerResourceProvier. When I do a search for a Practitioner Resource, the Narrative Template is not generated. I receive this message in the log:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO ca.uhn.fhir.narrative.BaseThymeleafNarrativeGenerator - No narative template for resource profile: bundle
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO ca.uhn.fhir.narrative.BaseThymeleafNarrativeGenerator - No narative template for resource profile: practitioner
```

I dont have problem with the Patient Resource, the Narrative element is generated without problem with them.

I dont know why this happens, because there isnt any different with both Providers I think.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HAPI's narrative templates are created by hand, and we've only created them for some resource types (Patient, Observation, etc.). The types you list (Bundle, etc.) don't yet have templates written.

If you're interested in helping to write these templates, help is always appreciated ;)

Comment: Ok, I will be happy to help :)